# Exchange positions instead of resorting every element with Jquery ui sortable plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using the Jquery UI sortable plugin for sorting a layout of avatars.
And when you sort with this plugin you change the position of every element, if you drop the first element on the fourth place the second element takes the first position, the third element takes the second position and so on... so every element moves 1 up or 1 down. I need for them just to modify the ones are being dragged and dragged on to.

I need to do this because the layout is a 4x4 grid with the 4 squares in the middle fixed in place, those 4 squares in the middle MUST stay in the 2:2, 2:3, 3:2 and 3:3 position.
(actually for the plugin is just 6, 7, 10 and 11 position)
So, I know how to fix those 4 squares in the middle:

```
$(function() {
    $("#sortable").sortable({
      items: "div.ui-item:not(.ui-state-disabled)",
    });
  });
```

And almost good enough, I can't drag those 4 squares in the middle, and I can't drop anything on them, but I still can drag the first element and drop it after those 4 elements what it will make them move ahead all of them.

```
Before draggin anything
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     |
|     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |fixed|fixed|     |
|     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |fixed|fixed|     |
|     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     |
|     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+

After dragging the first square into the 3:4 place 2:4
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 1:2 |     |     |     |
|     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|fixed|fixed| 2:4 | 1:1 |
|     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |fixed|fixed|     |
|     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     |
|     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

So I'm looking a way for exchange the places, lets say exchange the 1:1 square with the 2:4 square and end up with just those two places changed and leave all the other positions has they are.
My idea is to avoid any change until I drop the element and once I drop it make conditions or whatever I need in order to accomplish that because for what I see in the doc there is no option for exchanging positions in this plugin.
Maybe I can easily manage this with another plugin?

Comment: Use `dragable` and `dropable` instead of `sortable`. Then you can implement your own semantics for what happens when you drop an item.

Comment: But I need the DOM to be changed, because I use an array of inputs given by the order of the elements in the DOM for saving the order on the db. And draggable and dropable doesn't set the order in the DOM, I think it will be more work.

Comment: You can write your own handler for the `drop` event, and change the DOM elements there.

Comment: Yea, sure, but the positioning of the drag/drop is relative to the parent element by the pixel? So I would have to compare the position by pixel between the one I'm moving and the other ones to know where am I moving it? That's why I say that it looks like to much work. There must be a faster way.

Comment: @arderoma you can address that in your drop function when you append the new items.

Answer (score 0):

Swap, what I was looking for was swapping them.
I couldn't find a way to do it with sortable plugin from Jquery UI without having to rewrite the entire plugin, comparing pixels and stuffs.
There is no event on the Jquery UI sortable for when you start dragging, so there was no way to stop it from moving the items around on dragging, if that makes any sense. (when you drag an item over the others, the others move around this one and change their positions. So even when on dropping you are able to set the proper order in a "swapping" way you still got all the items moved on the dragging)

So chatgpt ended up recommending another library called SortableJS with a built in "swap" option, after including it (not without having other issues) all I needed to do was this js snippet.

Sortable.create(document.getElementById('sortable'), {
draggable: '.ui-item:not(.ui-state-disabled)',
swap: true,
});

PD: in case anyone encounters the same issue, I had to include this SortableJS library using RequireJS because I was getting module problems and/or compatibility with other JS libraries, I'm not sure.